# Change textsize of checkbox

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I want to change the textsize of a Checkbox.

How is this be made?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `FontSize` property.

Answer (score 0):

click on the checkbox, press f4 for the properties block then go to font and click on the plus sign, go to size under it, enter your desired size...
thats it

Comment: not failed, he just did it with the designer (ok, the designer is a fail, but that's another point :-) )